# How to add an ACF field as a class to a div

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, filter, advanced-custom-fields

I created a set of filters in static html and js but now I'm converting everything to WP I am having a problem. My tags are like so:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 filterDiv <?php the_sub_field('language'); ?> <?php the_sub_field('theme'); ?> <?php the_sub_field('media'); ?>">
    <h2>English Crime Video</h2>
</div>
```

However, it does not work because I think the "" are not causing the file to enter php mode. I cannot work out how to place the quotes to workaround this?

UPDATE:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php if( have_rows('about_additional_info') ):
        while( have_rows('about_additional_info') ): the_row(); ?>
            <div class="col-lg-4 filterDiv <?php the_sub_field('language'); ?> <?php the_sub_field('theme'); ?> <?php the_sub_field('media'); ?>">
                <h2>English Crime Video</h2>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
    endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: *welcome to stackoverflow!* can you get the values to display as actual text in the html?  try moving them to in or next to the h2 tag just to verify you're actually getting the output.  the quotes should not prohibit php from executing.

Comment: Have you specified which parent it's coming from? If it is a ```sub_field```, like you have written in your question - then you need to specify the parent in order for ACF to read it.

Comment: I have updated.

Comment: @LizCoder25 yes that looks like it should be working to me, i've copied your code into one of my projects and changed the fields to my names at worked fine. Are you putting these in your page loop? I've updated my answer with these amends.

Answer (score 0):

It should technically be working regardless of whether they are within class attr or not. Have you got it working elsewhere on the page?

I have also found in the past that I've had problems if there is no loop on the page. So make sure you are including the loop too.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); //start loop ?>

<?php if( have_rows('about_additional_info') ): while( have_rows('about_additional_info') ) : the_row(); ?>

<div class="col-lg-4 filterDiv <?php the_sub_field('language'); ?> <?php the_sub_field('theme'); ?> <?php the_sub_field('media'); ?>">
<h2>English Crime Video</h2>
</div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```